# what comes after what in a list

Tags: r, list

I am new to working with lists in R - given list of 3 string vectors, I would like to know either TRUE or FALSE any strings where `foo` appears **after** `bar` (even if this happens multiple times)

Given the list:

```
 x <- list(c("foo", "bar", "baz"),c("bar", "foo", "baz", "foo"),c("baz", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"))

> x
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"

[[2]]
[1] "bar" "foo" "baz" "foo"

[[3]]
[1] "baz" "bar" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```

How would one come up with an output of using a list index in R?

`[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the first instance of each of **foo** and **bar** (i.e. which appears first)

```
sapply(x, function(vec) min(which(vec == 'foo')) > min(which(vec=='bar')))
```

If you mean that *any* instance of **foo** appears after *any* instance of **bar**

```
sapply(x, function(vec) max(which(vec == 'foo')) > min(which(vec=='bar')))
```

Comment: c('foo','bar','foo','baz') would give false.  You probably want to search for the last instance of 'foo' instead of the first.

Comment: @Dason that should be false though (foo before bar = FALSE, foo after bar = TRUE)

Comment: Should it? Is there anything in the question that states that it should be false?  We do have a foo after a bar in the example I provide.

Comment: @Dason Fair point, I assumed he meant the first instance but you're right, it is ambiguous - edited

Answer (score 2):

One option is `match` to get the index of first occurrence of 'foo' and 'bar' and use that to create a logical `vector`

```
sapply(x, function(y) {i1 <- match(c("foo", "bar"), y); i1[1] > i1[2]})
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

or create the logical vector with `which`

```
sapply(x, function(y) which(y == "foo")[1] > which(y == "bar")[1])
```

---

or use regex after `paste`ing the elements

```
grepl("bar.*foo", sapply(x, paste, collapse = ' '))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```